# Show that this relation is an equivalence relation.

Tags: equivalence-relations

Given functions $$f_1 : A\to B$$and$$f_2 : A\to  B,$$ let us write $f_1 \equiv f_2$ when there exist bijections $\alpha : A\to A$ and $\beta : B \to B$ such that $f_2(\alpha(a)) = \beta(f_1(a))$ for all $a\in A_1$.

(a) Show that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation.

(b)How many equivalence classes of functions $f : A\to B$ such that $|A| = |B| = 3$ are there?

I tried to prove reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity.

Comment: Have you proven any of the three properties?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Proving reflexivity is very easy. Try using the simplest bijections $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you can think of.
2. For symmetry, try playing around with $\alpha^{-1}$ and $\beta^{-1}$.
3. For transitivity, write down what $f_1\equiv f_2$ and $f_2\equiv f_3$ means.

Comment: For reflexivity I have to show that f(α(a)) = β(f(a). But I don't understand, how can I use the bijectivity of α and β to prove it.

Comment: No, you have to *find* some bijections $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $f(\alpha(a))=\beta(f(a))$.